# I want to invert my mouse movement using OpenCV and python

Tags: python, opencv, web, mouseevent, virtual

while I'm moving my pointer to left the mouse is moving towards right and while moving to right its moving towards left...
I want my mouse to move exactly the same I move the pointer..

where my screen size is 1440*900

```
if len(cnts) > 0:
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)  #Finding the largest contour in the mask
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)  #Finding the minimum enclosing circle
        M = cv2.moments(c)  #Calculating image moment(center of mass)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])) #Centroid of the minimum enclosing circle
        bint = int(cv2.contourArea(c))
        if radius > 5:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),(255,255,255), 2)  #Drawing a circle of thickness 2
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (226, 43, 138), -1) #Drawing centroid on the frame
            mouse.release(Button.left)
            mouse.position=(1440-(int(x)*1440)/1440,900-(int(y)*900)/900)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just the X axis is inverted, you can try this -

```
mouse.position=(1440-(1440-(int(x)*1440)/1440),900-(int(y)*900)/900)
```

If both the X and Y axes are inverted -

```
mouse.position=(1440-(1440-(int(x)*1440)/1440),900-(900-(int(y)*900)/900))
```